# Cannot Access the file using Samba

Tags: linux, windows, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have set the following properties in smb.conf for the folder "Share"

```
[Share]
path = /home/root/Desktop/Share
available = yes
valid users = root
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

but I can't access this folder from my Windows Server 2012. I can see the folder but don't have the permission to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mapping the share](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/map-a-network-drive-using-windows-vista-or-windows-server-2008/). Following the guide linked, it should be very a similar to the process for Windows Server 2012. However, ensure you tick the "Connect with different credentials" (or similar) box. A box should now appear asking for your username and password. Here, you would enter the root username and password in their relevant sections. Once done, the share should be mapped to a drive, if complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified `valid users = root`, that means only the user `root` can access this share. What you need to do is, run:

```
smbpasswd -a root
```

It will ask you for the password of new user `root`. After you're done, try again to access the share with user root and the password you just set.

Comment: The samba share is on linux. Root is the 'master' user on linux, it already exists.

Comment: My understanding is that a samba user is different than a Linux user. `smbpasswd -a root` adds a `samba` user named `root`, which is different from the Linux `root` user. I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Removing the parameter valid users does not help. Also I have already done smdpasswd.